# Removing redundant code using generic in java

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a few methods which look similar to these,

```
`public List<sameReturnType> input1Converter(List<Inputt1> inputList)
        {
            List<sameReturnType> sameReturnTypeList = Lists.newArrayList();
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(inputList))
            {

                List<Input1> matchedInputs = Lists.newArrayList();

                sameReturnTypeList.addAll(inputList.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(in -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(in.getterMenthod()))
                        .filter(in -> in.getterMenthod().compareTo(Enum.key) == 0)
                        .map(in -> {
                            matchedInputs.add(in);
                            return converter.convert(in, sameReturnType.class);
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

                inputList.removeAll(matchedInputs);
            }
            return sameReturnTypeList;
        }

         public List<sameReturnType> input2Converter(List<Inputt2> inputList)
        {
            List<sameReturnType> sameReturnTypeList = Lists.newArrayList();
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(inputList))
            {

                List<Input2> matchedInputs = Lists.newArrayList();

                sameReturnTypeList.addAll(inputList.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(in -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(in.getterMenthod()))
                        .filter(in -> in.getterMenthod().compareTo(Enum.key) == 0)
                        .map(in -> {
                            matchedInputs.add(in);
                            return converter.convert(in, sameReturnType.class);
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

                inputList.removeAll(matchedInputs);
            }

            return sameReturnTypeList;
        }
```

`

This where these methods are called ,

```
 List<sameReturnType>.addAll(input1Converter(input1List));
 List<sameReturnType>.addAll(input2Converter(input2List));
```

I am trying to remove the redundant code by using generics. My output for all methods are the same , what changes is the list of sources. Method inside source class is the same for all sources

```
Any suggestions on this?  I want to have single method as most (everything) code is same for all these methods.
```

Comment: Do `Inputt1` and `Inputt2` implement a common interface containing the `getterMenthod` method?

Comment: Thanks, @AndyTurner , those plain POJO classes like DTO from the third party. We are using them in our services. Input1 and input2 don't implement any interface. These library classes for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Inputt1` and `Inputt2` implement a common interface containing the `getterMenthod` method, then you can simply change the parameter type to a bounded wildcard:

```
public List<sameReturnType> input1Converter(List<? extends CommonType> inputList)
```

And use `? extends CommonType` in place of `Input1` etc.

---

Otherwise, you'd need to provide a getter function:

```
public <T> List<sameReturnType> input1Converter(List<? extends T> inputList, Function<T, ReturnTypeOfGetterMethod> fn)
```

and then use `fn.apply(in)` in place of `in.getterMenthod()`, and invoke like:

```
input1Converter(listOfInputt1, Inputt1::getterMenthod)
input1Converter(listOfInputt2, Inputt2::getterMenthod)
```

---

By the way, your use of streams here is pretty crazy. Don't add things to other collections in `map` functions.

This might be clearer, and more obviously correct:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(inputList)) return Lists.newArrayList();

List<Input1> matchedInputs = inputList.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(in -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(in.getterMenthod()))
    .filter(in -> in.getterMenthod().compareTo(Enum.key) == 0)
    .collect(toList());

List<sameReturnType> sameReturnTypeList = matchedInputs.stream()
    .map(in -> converter.convert(in, sameReturnType.class))
    .collect(toList());

inputList.removeAll(matchedInputs);

return sameReturnTypeList;
```